# multiple table query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to query 4 tables(it works well when I query first 3 tables) and my table structure looks like,

1 Table - category

```
catid   catname
1       AAA
2       BBB
```

2 Table - questions

```
quid   qtype
1      data
2      
3      data
```

3 Table - answers

```
ansid   quid   catid   userid   answer
1       1      1       1        test1
2       2      1       1        test2
3       3      2       1        test3
```

4 Table - concerns

```
concern_id   catid   userid   ansid
1            1       1        1
2            1       4        3
```

Now my query is(with 3 tables)

```
SELECT category.catname,questions.quid,answers.catid,answers.ansid,answers.answer

FROM questions , answers ,category

where  questions.qtype = 'data' 

and questions.quid = answers.quid 

and category.catid = answers.catid 

and answers.userid = 1
```

And it gives me(which is fine)

```
catname   quid   catid   ansid   answer
AAA       1      1       1       test1
BBB       3      2       3       test3
```

Now I want to include the 4th table in the query and the resultant should look like

```
concern_id   catname   quid   catid   ansid   answer
1             AAA       1      1       1       test1
null          BBB       3      2       3       test3
```

And here I am stuck with the query.

Comment: Try using [joins](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)

Comment: Bit confused to use left join as there are 4 tables so not sure which one to keep as left table and which one to as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT category.catname,questions.quid,answers.catid,answers.ansid,answers.answer

FROM 
questions 
INNER JOIN answers  on (questions.quid = answers.quid )
INNER JOIN category cat on (category.catid = answers.catid)
LEFT JOIN concerns con on (concerns.userId = answers.userId and concerns.catid = answers.catid  AND concerns.ansid = answers.ansid )
where  questions.qtype = 'data' 

and answers.userid = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Sashi...I modified the query a bit and worked like charm.I was doing left join on first 3 tables....what an idiot I was well still I am... :D Thanks for the help

Comment: Great that t helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use joins:

```
SELECT category.catname,questions.quid,answers.catid,answers.ansid,answers.answer

FROM category

join answers 
on category.catid = answers.catid 

join questions
on questions.quid = answers.quid

join concern
on concerns.userId = answers.userId and concerns.catid = answers.catid  AND      concerns.ansid = answers.ansid

where  questions.qtype = 'data' 
and answers.userid = 1
```

Comment: Forgot to include the last table :)

Answer (score 1):

Its not necessary to use joins. MySQL will compile the joined version to the same result as this version.

I think you should combine them by ansid.

```
SELECT concern.concern_id, category.catname, questions.quid, answers.catid, answers.ansid, answers.answer

FROM questions, answers, category, concerns

where questions.qtype = 'data' 

and concerns.ansid = answers.ansid

and questions.quid = answers.quid 

and category.catid = answers.catid 

and answers.userid = 1
```

Comment: Describe the problem of the solution.